# {{ content.field_test }} doesn't work in node.html.twig

Tags: 8, theming, nodes

I created a field whose machine name is *field_test*. I want to show this field in node.html.twig, but when I use `{{ content.field_test }}`, `{{ content.field_test.value }}`, or `{{ content.field_test[0] }}` the field is not printed.

How can I achieve this in Drupal 8.3.5?

Comment: {{ content.field_test}} is enough. It will work. Check node.html.twig is working or not first .

Comment: Yes node.html.twig work but {{ content.field_test }} not work.

Comment: In older version it's worked but now not work !!

Comment: You know you can only print fields configured in the display mode of the content type?

Comment: Yes. with {{ node.field_test.value }} just show value of some field . But I want print the full HTML markup of the field.

Comment: {{ node }} has access to all fields from the database, for {{ content }} you need to add them first in the content type in *Manage Display*, where you can also configure how the full HTML markup is formatted.

Comment: I do this but not work.

Comment: Who can help me?

Comment: Are you using the correct machine name? double check on "Manage Fields" under the Machine Name column.

Comment: Yes I use the correct machine name.

Comment: I had the same issue and found that deinstalling the experimental module *Field Layout* solved the problem.

Comment: I'd reinforce comment from @4k4, go to your content type field display settings, and ensure your field is set to `visible` for your display mode like 'default', 'teaser', etc... Otherwise, just print `{{ content }}`, do you see your field?

Answer (score 4):

Uninstalling Field Layout module will solve this. (tested with Drupal 8.6.10, using subtheme built on Barrio Bootstrap 4).

Answer (score 1):

```
{{ content.field_test }}
```

Should just work  but make sure

- you the field is not hidden by going to `admin/structure/types/manage/CONTENTTYPE/display` and making sure the field is NOT in the disabled fields
- its not hidden because of some changes in `hook_preprocess_node` in your theme or a parent theme

Investigate further either by

- installing `devel` and `kint` modules (kint is a submodule of devel) and `{{kint(content)}}`
- within `hook_preprocess_node` using a xdebug or `print` or `print_r` statements